# Use QT to convert HTML into XML

Tags: html, c++, xml, qt

I saw a lot threads about converting html to XML but any thread contain QT subject.

I try to convert HTML into XML using this function:

```
static std::string CleanHTML(const std::string &html){
    QWebPage * tmp_webpage = new QWebPage();
    tmp_webpage->mainFrame()->setHtml(QString::fromStdString(html));

    QWebElement * tmp = &tmp_webpage->mainFrame()->documentElement();

    return tmp->toOuterXml().toStdString();
}
```

It doesn't working. This function return 99% the same code as HTML contain.

**EDIT:: (sorry of unclear question)**

1. It is possible to convert HTML into XML using QT? (Output XML format must be supported by [pugiXML](http://pugixml.org/) - i want to use it to parse XML - (i know that by QT i can parse HTML))
2. If YES, why my func dont work ? Could you fix that, or show me how to do it in other way?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "convert" HTML into XML?  It's not clear what that involves.

Comment: Change HTML code from site to XML code, and parse XML (for ex. by : [parser](https://code.google.com/p/pugixml/) )( i know that i can parse HTML in QT)

Comment: Valid HTML is XML. So you are talking about same things.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov No, only XHTML is XML.  HTML itself is derived from SGML, which is related to XML but not really compatible.

Comment: @ThomasAndrees It's still unclear what you're asking.  What format would the XML be in?

Comment: I want the XML which can i parse in [pugiXML](https://code.google.com/p/pugixml/) . So what format is this XML?